# Catching the position of the mouse on a keyPressEvent in pyqtgraph ViewBox

Tags: pyqtgraph, pyqt6, viewbox

I'm trying to get the position of the mouse on a `keyPressEvent` of a custom `pg.ViewBox`.
The only solution I've found so far is to create some crosshairs and get the position of those on a `keyPressEvent`. Is there a better way to do this without crosshairs?

Also, in the example I give, when I press a key, the first time nothing happens and the second time, I get a strange undecipherable error message, followed by the expected behavior (which is to print the position of the cursor) but repeated many many times:

```
Error in sys.excepthook:

Original exception was:
Mouse position from crosshairs: [0.3896103896103896, 0.5307017543859649]
Mouse position from crosshairs: [0.3896103896103896, 0.5307017543859649]
Mouse position from crosshairs: [0.3896103896103896, 0.5307017543859649]
...
```

I would be  grateful for any clue about what is going on.

Here is a minimal working example:

```py
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys

class CrosshairViewBox(pg.ViewBox):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        pg.ViewBox.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
    
        self.crosshair_x = pg.InfiniteLine(
            angle=90, movable=False
        )
        self.crosshair_y = pg.InfiniteLine(
            angle=0, movable=False
        )
        self.addItem(self.crosshair_x, ignoreBounds=True)
        self.addItem(self.crosshair_y, ignoreBounds=True)

    def activate_crosshairs(self):
        self.scene().sigMouseMoved.connect(self.move_crosshair)

    def move_crosshair(self, ev):
        """
            This is triggered on a sigMouseMoved which sends a position as an event
        """
        pos = ev
        if self.sceneBoundingRect().contains(pos):
            mousePoint = self.mapSceneToView(ev)
            self.crosshair_x.setPos(mousePoint.x())
            self.crosshair_y.setPos(mousePoint.y())

    def keyPressEvent(self, ev):
        """
            In this case, ev is a QKeyEvent, for which I cannot get
            the position of the mouse. So I have to use the crosshairs.
        """
        self.scene().keyPressEvent(ev)
        posx = self.crosshair_x.getPos()[0]
        posy = self.crosshair_y.getPos()[1]
        print(f"Mouse position from crosshairs: [{posx}, {posy}]")

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True)
    chvb = CrosshairViewBox()
    win.addItem(chvb)
    chvb.activate_crosshairs()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to complicate things by creating other items. Just store the mouse position as an instance attribute:

```py
class CrosshairViewBox(pg.ViewBox):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwds)
        self.mousePoint = QtCore.QPointF()

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == self.GraphicsItemChange.ItemSceneChange and value:
            # automatically connect the signal when added to a scene
            value.sigMouseMoved.connect(self.mouse_moved)
            self.setFocus()
        return super().itemChange(change, value)

    def mouse_moved(self, pos):
        self.mousePoint = self.mapSceneToView(pos)

    def keyPressEvent(self, ev):
        print("Mouse position from crosshairs: [{}, {}]".format(
            self.mousePoint.x(), self.mousePoint.y()))
```

Also, do not call `self.scene().keyPressEvent(ev)` as it would probably cause recursion (which may be what causes the error you are seeing).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thanks ! But if I run your example not all the keyEvents are captured. It seems as though as soon as the mouse moves the ViewBox loses focus? When I click again inside the ViewBox it captures the keyEvents again but only until I move the mouse.

Comment: We can only base answers based on the code and context provided in the question, if you had other objects, you should have at least included some them in your question. That said, I've not studied pyqtgraph classes in depth, so I don't know for sure how its focus management works, but if you need a "global" keyboard handling, you should probably use a GraphicsLayoutWidget subclass and implement the `keyPressEvent()` in it, then eventually check if the given point is within the boundaries of the viewbox before using its value.